# Power factor for impedance

Tags: electric-circuits

I need to compute the power factor for two ideal impedances, a capacitor:

$$Z_C=\frac{-j}{\omega C} $$

and a inductor:

$$Z_L=j\omega L $$

I know that the power factor is defined as a term $\cos(\phi)$, but I don't know how to compute it in terms of $Z_C$ and $Z_L$. Moreover I need to discuss wether $\cos(\phi)$ is a function of $\omega$, the frequency of the AC circuit.

Any hint or reference will be appreciated. I'm translating those terms into english so I hope that my question doesn't sound wierd or is even well defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With no real impedance as part of the load the power factor is 0 because your impedance phase angle is either -90 (capacitor) or +90 (inductor).  You need some resistance for the power factor to be non-zero.

Compute the impedance in polar coordinates to get the phase and you'll be able to answer your own questions about frequency dependence and the impact of having a real load vs pure imaginary load.

Edit:  Power factor is a ratio of the real power to the total apparent power.  Real power is dissipated as heat and reactive power is stored in an electric (capacitor) or magnetic (inductor) field.  Since humans are usually only interested in power that does work (i.e. real power) we have defined the power factor as a ratio of real power (P) to apparent power (S).  This definition works out nicely so all you need to know is the phase angle of the impedance to compute the power factor and know how much real power is dissipated.

So to answer your question, first off there's no real resistance so no real work can be done so real power=0 which implies power factor=0.  Secondly I also know that j or -j in complex math is just +90 or -90 for an impedance phase angle and the power factor=cos(impedance phase angle)=0 for 90 and -90 again implying power factor=0.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. That the impedance phase angle is $\pm 90$ implies that the power factor is 0 because it is the cosine of that angle?

Comment: @Nivalth more or less yes.  It really has more to do with the idea that no real work is being done. I tried to explain it a little more in my edit.

Comment: @Nivalth it occurred to me that maybe you're stuck because you need to know how to convert a complex number Z=a + jb to a polar form when a=0.  Try looking up a tutorial on complex to polar conversions and set a=0 (your specific case) and see what the phase angle looks like.

Comment: no, that was no the problem but thank you anyway. Your answer worked pretty well